# Why Are My File Contents Disappearing & How Do I Properly Read From This File?

Tags: c, save, data-retrieval

I have a connect 4 program that allows user input for number of rows/columns & the length of the connection required to win. The program works such that at any point during the game you can type "save" instead of the column you want your game-piece to be placed, and the game settings (num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win) will be written to a file called settings.txt

I can confirm that this works and settings.txt holds the data like so:

7 7 4

where each number is a setting and there is a space afterwards.

Now, I'm trying to read in these integers & set them equal to the according variables as a start to my (hopefully successful) load-game method; however, when I try using fscanf in the way that is illustrated in the code below, nothing happens... and when I look at settings.txt afterwards, it is blank.. why is this?

main method

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 

setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
printf("Starting Game\n");  


// the default values for board size if no command line arguments are used
int index;
int num_rows = 7;
int num_columns = 7;
int length_to_win = 4;
FILE *fp = fopen("settings.txt", "r");


// this loop checks for command line arguments and sets game variables accordingly.
for(index = 0; index < argc; ++index) {

    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-l", 5) == 0 ) {
      fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-h", 5) == 0 ) {
      num_rows =atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-height", 5) == 0 ) {
      num_rows =atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-w", 5) == 0 ) {
      num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-width", 5) == 0 ) {
      num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-s", 5) == 0 ) {
      num_rows = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
      num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-square", 5) == 0 ) {
      num_rows = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
      num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-c", 5) == 0 ) {
      length_to_win = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
    if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-connect", 5) == 0 ) {
      length_to_win = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
    }
}



// these conditionals check for valid board size
if (num_rows <= 0 || num_columns <= 0 ){
    printf("%s\n","You entered a width or length that was invalid." );
}
if (length_to_win <= 0 || length_to_win > (num_rows - 1)) {
    printf("%s\n","You entered a winning length that was invalid." );
}


// this creates the board
int array[num_rows][num_columns];
initialize(num_rows, num_columns, array);
int answer;
int player = 0;

printf("%s\n", "*********************");
printf("%s\n", "   Starting Board   ");
printf("%s\n", "*********************");
puts("\n");
printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, array);
puts("\n");
printf("Player: %ds Turn\n", player + 1);  


/*Start game loop*/
while(1) {       

    // prompts the user to select which column they want their piece to be placed
    // -1 on the temp because the first column is technically 0 so if a player
    // wants to place their piece in column "1", it'll be placed at index[0] accordingly
    printf("%s\n", "Enter Column # To Place Token"); 
    int column;
    char temp[20];       
    scanf("%s", temp); 

    if (strncmp (temp, "save", 5) == 0){

        // this writes the game settings to a file
        int *rows = &num_rows;
        int *cols = &num_columns;
        int *len = &length_to_win;
        FILE *fp = fopen("settings.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", *rows);
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", *cols);
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", *len);
        printf("Game Saved\n");
        fclose(fp);

    }
    else {
        column = atoi(temp) - 1; 
    }

    if ((column < 0 || column > (num_columns - 1)) && (strncmp (temp, "save", 5) != 0) ) {
        printf("%s\n","You entered a column that was invalid. Please try again." );
        continue;
    }

    int attmpt = place_token(player, column, num_rows, num_columns, array);
    if (attmpt != 1 && (strncmp (temp, "save", 5) != 0)) {
        printf("%s\n","This row is already full. Please try again." );
        continue;
    }

    printf("%s\n", "************************");
    printf("%s\n", "      Board Updated     ");
    printf("%s\n", "************************");  
    puts("\n");  
    printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, array);
    puts("\n");




    if (checkFullBoard(num_rows, num_columns, array)) {
        printf("%s\n","This game is a tie. Thanks for Playing.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // this if-statement will constantly be run while the game progresses, 
    // meaning that winner will be called at every turn and 
    // all of the win conditions will be checked until a winner is found
    int isWin = winner(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, array);
    if(isWin != -1) {
        char temp2[20];
        printf("Player: %d is the winner! Thanks for Playing.\n", isWin + 1);
        printf("Play again? (enter 'y' to continue)\n");
        scanf("%s", temp2);

        if (strncmp (temp2, "y", 5) == 0){
          initialize(num_rows, num_columns, array);
          printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, array);
        }
        else {
          printf("Game over, goodbye!\n");
          return 0;
        }
    }

    // if a winner is not found then this if/else will continue to switch
    // between players at the end of each turn
    if ((strncmp (temp, "save", 5) != 0)) {
        if (player == 1) {
          player = 0;
      }
        else {
            player = 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Player: %ds Turn\n", player +1);
} // end of while loop

return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: try "a" instead of "w+"

Comment: @silentboy that worked, thank you.

Comment: There are a number of weak spots in the code.  1) after calling `fopen()` check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) `argv[0]` is the name of the executable, not the first parameter.  3) when a number is extracted from the command line parameters, the index needs to be advanced enough so that number is not processed as if it might be a `-x` value

Comment: this kind of line: `if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-square", 5) == 0 )` is not correct.  the `-square` is a total (including the NUL terminator) of 8 characters, but only 4 are actually being checked.  There are multiple instances of this problem when checking the command line parameters,   Why use `strncmp()` when what is really needed is `strcmp()`

Comment: when ANY invalid command line parameter (or no command line parameters) the code should output a USAGE statement to stderr and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in stdlib.h

Comment: when calling `fscanf()` always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In this statement: `fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win);`  any other value than 3 indicates an error so should be followed by: `perror( "fscanf for saved game parameters failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: these two lines: `int array[num_rows][num_columns];
initialize(num_rows, num_columns, array);` can be replaced with this single statement: `int array[num_rows][num_columns] = { 0 };`

Comment: when calling `scanf()` with a `%s` format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer, so the user cannot overflow the buffer.  Such overflow results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  I.E. `scanf("%19s", temp);`  (remember to also check the returned value, which, in this case, if not 1 then an error occurred.

Comment: before the second call to `fopen()`, call `fclose()` on the file pointer, AND on multiple events where the user enters `save`, the file will grow, but the code is only setup to read the first entry. so all following entries are not accessed.   What happens the first time, if the file is not yet in existence and the user uses the `-l` command line parameter?

Comment: the posted code never lets the user know that they can type `save` rather than the column number to enable saving the current game parameters

Comment: why all this fiddling: ` int *rows = &num_rows;
        int *cols = &num_columns;
        int *len = &length_to_win;
        FILE *fp = fopen("settings.txt", "w+");
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", *rows);
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", *cols);
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", *len);`  all that is needed is: `FILE *fp = fopen( "settings.txt", "w" ); fprintf(fp, "%d %d %d", num_rows, num_columns, len_to_win); fflush( fp ); fclose();`
`

Comment: regarding this expression: `(column < 0 || column > (num_columns - 1)) && (strncmp (temp, "save", 5)`  it is impossible for `save` AND any specific value in `column` to occur at the same time,  And when `save` was entered, then `column` is not initialized.  Checking an uninitialized variable for any value is undefined behavior.

Comment: the posted code (sortof) enables the user to select a column for their next token BUT does not enable the player to select a row.  is that what you really want?

Comment: since there is no code to enable the computer to fill a spot on the board, all the user has to do is type `0 1 2 3`  and they will have 4 in a row.  Suggest re-thinking the game play, the application data flow and the application control flow

Comment: what happens if the user types `alpha` rather than `save` or a column number?

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by silentboy the solution was replacing "w+" with "a."